# How do I refresh data on an Access form?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm building a MS Access database that will contain orders of raw materials.
I have a Form that I use to load orders into a table.
My Raw Materials are identified with an MP_Code field and a MP_Name field which are present into my form in a combo box.
I would like to select raw materials from their MP_Code or their MP_Name (combo box in a form) and then refresh the other field (combo) after one of them has been selected by the user.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

On the `AfterUpdate` event after each combobox, you can use the `Requery` method to refresh the data in the opposite comobobx.

So, a quick example:

```
Private Sub MP_Code_AfterUpdate()

Me.MP_Name.Requery

End Sub
```

## What does `Requery` do?

- Reruns the underlying data source (other controls, table/query, etc) for the combobox
- Displays any new or changes records or removes deleted records (makes sense since it's updating the underlying data)
- Updates records displays based on any changes to the `Filter` property of the form. (Again, makes sense. This is what I would expect it to do.)